# Не выводит sprintf

Tags: php, строки

```
 echo '<ul>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
                $mes = $row->message;
                $format = "<li class='message'>%s</li>";
                sprintf($format,$mes);
            }
            echo '</ul>';
```

где тут неправильно

```
                $mes = $row->message;
                $format = "<li class='message'>%s</li>";
                sprintf($format,$mes);
```

Comment: echo sprintf() ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sprintf() возвращает строку, а не выводит на экран.
Дока http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php
Правильно так:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
            $mes = $row->message;
            $format = "<li class='message'>%s</li>";
            echo sprintf($format,$mes);
        }
```